# This Mysql Trigger get me this error subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Product_Trigger
    AFTER UPDATE ON PRODUCT
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AUDITTRAIL
    SET activity = 'updated Product',
     employeeName = (select (select concat(firstName,' ',LastName) from employee) from userAccount where accountstatus = 1),
        employeeID = (select employeeID from userAccount where accountStatus=1),
        activityDate = NOW();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This error speaks for itself: one  or more of your SELECTs returns more than one row, and you are inserting only one row.

Comment: use LIMIT 1  with sub-queries

Comment: @ManojSingh maybe that will give the wrong result, he has to be more specific in his query

Comment: @MichaelO. for more specific result need to update WHERE conditions, but if sub queries returning multiple with all required consitions then LIMIT can be used.

Comment: if you're trying to get information specifically from the row which was just updated (which would make sense, in the context of an UPDATE trigger) then you can get it via the `new` object...

Comment: P.S. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html for more info and examples.